# How can I access attributes in class instances held inside an instance of another class?

Tags: python, class, inner-classes, attributeerror

I am creating a stock screener with Python. My data looks like this. Because of the format of the data, I am trying to use nested classes (I think that's what I am doing) to be able to reference the data. [Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ONQH.png)

Here is the code for my classes:

```py
class FieldClass:
    def __init__(self, parts):
        if parts[2].replace(" ", "") == 'Price':
            self.price = YearClass(parts)
        elif parts[2].replace(" ", "") == 'Revenues':
            self.rev = YearClass(parts)
        elif parts[2].replace(" ", "") == 'OperatingIncome':
            self.opincome = YearClass(parts)
        elif parts[2].replace(" ", "") == 'OperatingMargin':
            self.opmargin = YearClass(parts)
        elif parts[2].replace(" ", "") == 'NetProfitMargin':
            self.profitmargin = YearClass(parts)

class YearClass:
    # creates a class whose objects/attributes are a dict of each year of data
    def __init__(self, parts):
        self.years_data = dict()
        self.years_data[2009] = (parts[3])
        self.years_data[2010] = (parts[4])
        self.years_data[2011] = (parts[5])
        self.years_data[2012] = (parts[6])
        self.years_data[2013] = (parts[7])
        self.years_data[2014] = (parts[8])
        self.years_data[2015] = (parts[9])
        self.years_data[2016] = (parts[10])
        self.years_data[2017] = (parts[11])
        self.years_data[2018] = (parts[12])
        self.years_data[2019] = (parts[13])
```

Here is how I call/reference the classes in my code:

```py
def data_prep(fname):
    tkr_list = []
    data_dict = dict()

with open(fname) as f_in:
    f_in.readline()
    for lines in f_in:
        parts = lines.strip('\n').split(",")
        tkr = parts[1]
        key_cat = parts[2].replace(" ", "")

        if tkr not in tkr_list:
            tkr_list.append(tkr)

    for tkr in tkr_list:
        data_dict[tkr] = FieldClass(parts)

var = data_dict['FLWS'].opincome.years_data[2010]
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'FieldClass' object has no attribute 'opincome'
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your instance of `FieldClass` won't have an `opincom` attribute unless this statement is true: `parts[2].replace(" ", "") == 'OperatingIncome'`. So, it appears that statement is never true. This should be easy to debug: have you verified that `parts[2].replace(" ", "")` is what you think it is?

Comment: FWIW, your classes aren't nested. One of them just contains instances of the other. "Nested" would defining one _inside_ the other, which isn't used all that often in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have defaults set for your attributes, and they will only be set if the correct condition is met - as such, could it be that your input data does not have an `OperatingIncome` set and therefore your class is not having that attribute set / made to exist?

Answer (score 0):

Your error as nothing to deal with nested class.
The issue is on your **init function** in `class FieldClass`.

You're setting your class attributes on conditions so if the condition is not met your class won't have this attribute.

In this case it's `opincome` attribute

Here is your options:

- set default attributes
- remove these conditions
- **change your code in a way that FieldClass loads all your necessary attributes** (price, rev, opincome, ...). *I recommand you this option*